# Lost value of enum pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, enums, stack

I have the following:

```
enum class color_t {BLEU, RED};

class Evaluator{
    Foo my_foo;

    int initalise(){
        color_t* ptr_my_color = NULL;
        color_t my_color = color_t::BLEU;
        ptr_my_color = &my_color;
        my_foo = new Foo(ptr_my_color);
    }

    int run(){my_foo.run();}
}

class Foo{
    color_t* ptr_my_color;
    public:
        Dist(color_t* ptr_my_color = NULL) {
            this->ptr_my_color = ptr_my_color;
        }
        int run(){
            if(ptr_my_color!=NULL){
                if((*ptr_my_color)==color_t::BLEU){
                    cerr << "1st if" << endl;
                } else { 
                    cerr << "1st else" << endl;
                }
            }
            //do some stuff
            if(ptr_my_color!=NULL){
                if((*ptr_my_color)==color_t::BLEU){
                    cerr << "2nd if" << endl;
                } else { 
                    cerr << "2nd else" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Evaluator my_eval();
    my_eval.initalise();
    my_eval.run();
}
```

This prints out:

```
1st if
2nd else
```

Why ist that? My guess: the non-pointer enum `color_t my_color` is created on the stack and when `initialise()` finishes, it is tagged as "feel free to overwrite". Then in the first `if` the pointer can still find it but doing the other stuff overwrites it and then it isn't found anymore? But why does it still pass `if(ptr_my_color!=NULL){`?

How do I solve it? By giving the `class Foo` also a member variable `color_t my_color` and creating the enum again in the constructor?

Comment: A couple of points: (1) this code doesn't compile - please make it easy for people to help you by posting working code that replicates your problem; (2) It seems highly likely that `//do some stuff` contains something relevant to your problem. So again, please make sure this code replicates the problem.

Comment: Your code just screams UB. You create a variable on the stack, and then pass pointer to it to constructor of member object, and expect it to work after that said local variable goes out of scope. In addition, why shouldn't it pass your non-null check? You didn't set your pointer to null upon leaving the scope.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius: After running into the error, I did realise why it's wrong, but I'm unsure of what the correct way would be. Should I use unique_ptr or should I pass the variable as a reference instead? (I didn't so far to allow calling the constructor with that variable not set) Or should I just re-create the enum in the new scope? I'm still new to C++ so any tipy or links where I can read up on this are greatly appreciated. The only neat way I see, is to just use an `int` after all but that way I wouldn't learn anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest passing the `enum class` to the constructor as a **const reference**, and include an `INVALID` value to flag the "not set" case:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum class color_t {BLEU, RED, INVALID};

class Foo{
    color_t my_color;
public:
    Foo(color_t const& color = color_t::INVALID) {
        my_color = color;
    }
    void run(){
        if(my_color!=color_t::INVALID){
            if(my_color==color_t::BLEU){
                cerr << "1st if" << endl;
            } else { 
                cerr << "1st else" << endl;
            }
        }
        //...
    }
};

class Evaluator{
    Foo* my_foo;
public:
    void initalise(){
        color_t my_color = color_t::BLEU;
        my_foo = new Foo(my_color);
    }
    // ...
};
```

The key difference here is actually the change of the member `my_color` to a simple type rather than a pointer. This means that in the constructor of `Foo`, at the line `my_color = color` you actually take a **copy** of `color` and store it as `my_color`. You then don't need to worry whether `color` is a reference to something on the stack that might get cleared up (as you do in your pointer case).

Even when passing as a pointer, you could get the same effect by storing as a simple type, and taking a copy in the constructor like this: `my_color = *ptr_my_color`. However, I'd certainly prefer using references in this case.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for! I had several ideas how it could be fixed, but being new to C++ I'm often unsure which route would be the best to go and you cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 0):

It still passes the check because that pointer is not null, if you go check it, points to somewhere in memory aka is not null. Proper way would be to wrap that in s unique_ptr, or if for some reason you want to handle the raw pointer you should free the data  and set the pointer to null, even though in this dummy test the heap allocation is not really needed.